# how to return xml using ctx in expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, ctx

How can i return xml using ctx from msw package?

now i using this code:

```
const endpointHandler = (req, res, ctx) => {
  const xml = `<test></test>`;

  return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.xml(xml));
};
```

but it's don't work

any help?

Answer (score 0):

ok i get it :

```
return res(ctx.xml(<test></test>));
```